# How to use ViewManager in CLI application?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

A have a simple Zend Framework 2 Console application. Some controller actions generate files (html, markdown, json etc). Example:

```
class ExampleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        // Create $contents...
        file_put_contents('./file.html', $contents);
        return 'File successfully created';
    }
}
```

I would like to use ViewManager to create files based on templates using view helpers. I added some settings to my module.config.php:

```
return [
    // ...
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

But I have no idea what to do next. How to use ViewManager in CLI application?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the viewrenderer service from controller or from a factory (with injected servicelocator):

```
$view = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');
```

With this $view, you can render a ViewModel object.

```
$content = $view->render($viewModel);
```

You can define the template on the ViewModel with setTemplate().